# How to compare on Laravel pivot amounts with table column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am really stuck with this.

I have a Many to Many relationship with Actors and Works. I need to get all the works that don't have all the actors they need. The actors needed per work is a property on the Works table called "extras_needed"

So far I've tried withCount, but you can't use it on a where. This is the closest thing I have which is:

```
$works = $works->has('actors','<','extras_needed');
```

But its trying to use extras_needed as a string and I need it to treat it as the column per se.

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: use: `$works = $works->has('actors', '<', \DB::raw('extras_needed'));`

Comment: @DerekPollard it works! you're awesome! want to add it as answer so I accept it?

Comment: sure can! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions):

> Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query.

Armed with this, we can turn your query into:

```
$works = $works->has('actors', '<', \DB::raw('extras_needed'));
```

Hope this helped!